# SMTP mail error

Tags: smtp, email

Hello i have some problem when using SMTP mail using PHP.
when i am use mail  function that time always it shows 
errore Like **"Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"**

How can i slove this problem at (Project is on Cpanle)
 Kindly help me

Comment: Please add some detail to the question, such as what SMTP program are you using, and what is the output of "php -i"?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see a code snippet.

The error message suggests that you are using `fsockopen()` and passing it an http URL instead of an hostname.

You may also have an http url somewhere else (in your code or a config file) that is passed to `fsockopen()` at some point. Make sure your smtp server hostname doesn't start with `http://`.